# Performance wise what is better approach use Java object and convert to JSON String using some library or generate String directly using StringBuilder

Tags: java, android, json, string

In my current android program I want to transfer **very large size** of key value pair of integers to server using json string. Below are the two approaches, I just want to know which one is a best approach and why. I am going to run this program in android phones so I am worrying about creating lots of objects.

**Approach 1.**

```
public class DataBean {

    int dataKey = 0;
    int dataValue = 0;
}


ArrayList<DataBean> dataBeans = new ArrayList<DataBean>();

for(some condition){

    int dataKey = //Some operations to get Key
    int dataValue = //Some operations to get Value

    DataBean dataBean = new DataBean();
    dataBean.dataKey = dataKey;
    dataBean.dataValue = dataValue;

    dataBeans.add(dataBean);
}

//Here some JSON library like Jackson Jar to convert    ArrayList<DataBean> to JSON String
```

**Approach 2.**

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

for(some condition){

    int dataKey = //Some operations to get Key
    int dataValue = //Some operations to get Key

    stringBuilder.append("{"+dataKey+","+dataValue+"},"); //Generate Direct JSON String 


}

//Here direct JSON
String JSON = stringBuilder.toString();
```

Comment: You'll have to measure the performance yourself; we aren't a benchmarking service. Finally, a very large amount of key/value pairs is going to be slow no matter how you send it (that's what a large amount of data means).

Comment: I would say why reinvent the thing.. if the parsing api is available which is tested an widely used then one should go with it. Afaik jackson or some other API would be using reflection to get the attributes and build a json response while in your case it would be bounded by 2 variables only. If more variables required then you have to write more code, which seems a bit unnecessary to me. I would go with jackson for ease of using and maintaining code. And performance won't be that much drastically different. :)

Comment: If you perform any performance test would also like to see the result of it ... :)

Comment: Samwise Gamgee Thanks for your advice, Very helpful